# mod_rewrite: redirect to 404 page for non-directory and non-file requests issue

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have written below .htaccess to redirect the 404 pages for non-directory and non-file requests.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ / [R=404,L]
```

Comment: This reads like you forgot to mention one important detail: your actual issue...

Comment: The issue _might_ be your conditions here. They do not really make sense, do they? Since they apply the redirection rule to every request that does get mapped onto an existing file or directory inside your file system. Which probably is _not_ what you want. You probably want to remove the `[OR]` flag and negate the conditions to `!-f` and `!-d`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If the user hits this URL "https://example.com/test.php/aaa" it should be redirect to "https://example.com/test.php".  After the last slash, any text added by the user if it, not directory or file that should be redirected the same URL with trim last text and slash.